How to get IQ component file directly from SDR#
I'm using SDR# to capture the signals. I have used Baseband recorder to record the signals. But i'm getting data in .wav file. what exactly this .wav file contains(will it contain only IQ data)??And is there any other plugin to get directly IQ components??
I need answer for the queries i asked above. I have tried different plugins as Audio recorder, baseband recorder but in both cases  i got .wav file. If .wav file only contains IQ data then i can convert .wav file to IQ components file. But if .wav file contains any other data included then, it'll be messed up. so i want to know whether .wav file only contains IQ data or anyother included.
